# Ubuntu16.04 python3.6.5 cannot install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I hit a problem when trying to install tensorflow cpu version upon my ubuntu desktop.

I tried two:

1.`pip3 install tensorflow`

error here:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

2.`pip3 install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

```
tensorflow-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I googled a lot and find might be related to pip version, architecture .etc.

However, seems those are correct upon my desktop, here is my check:

```
148 wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ uname -i
x86_64
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ 
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l

wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ 
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ pip3 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ 
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ 
wni@wni-GE62-2QC:~⟫ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, May 12 2018, 17:43:57) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'ELF')
>>> 
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize('P')
8
```

What's more, pip3 search tensorflow can find tensorflow 1.8.0.

Um...anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

**[Edit]**
Solved by reinstall Python3.6.5 from source.
The reason for the first time is still unknown.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a Docker container based on Alpine (<10MB Linux) https://github.com/petronetto/docker-python-deep-learning (that one is based on debian:stretch-slim)

Comment: Sorry I don't wanna docker now, I just wanna try the installation step

Answer (score 0):

Yep tensorflow, horrid thing to install! You will be best off using a virtual environment and using the tf-nightly package with local requirements (as it is panickety about various other packages' versions, praw comes painfully to mind).

Comment: I just tried to install within virtualenv but with the same error

Comment: Not yet. But I think Anaconda is not required, eh?

Comment: if its not too much trouble, clear out your python env and install anaconda as your base python distro. from there use venv and you will be a lot better off